# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sequence" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, tomcat9

I created a Dynamic Web Project with the JPA facet running on Tomcat 9.0.24. I have a single table, called profile, in my Prostgres 10.10 database and I have a single entity "Profile" that I am trying to persist. I am using Eclipse 4.12.0.

The profile table was created using pgAdmin 4 console and it's sequence exists.

Here is my code...

Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Profile entity:

```
package za.co.ezimax.entity;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity()
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="first_name", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="birth_date", columnDefinition = "DATE",  nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name="sex", nullable = false)
    private int sex;

    @Column(name="mobile_mac", nullable = false)
    private String mobileMac;

    @Column(name="mobile_no", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String mobileNo;

    @Column(name="registration_date", columnDefinition = "DATE", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate registrationDate;

    @Column(name="user_password", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private char[] userPassword;

    public Profile() {
    }
}
```

Code to persist entity:

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ezimax");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setFirstName("Hendre");
        profile.setLastName("Louw");
        profile.setSex(1);
        profile.setMobileMac("ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff");
        profile.setMobileNo("+27832000000");
        profile.setRegistrationDate(LocalDate.now());
        profile.setUserPassword("password".toCharArray());

        em.persist(profile);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sequence" does not exist
  Position: 8
Error Code: 0
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, SEQ_GEN]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2096)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3349)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1895)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1877)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1842)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.update(QuerySequence.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.updateAndSelectSequence(QuerySequence.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.getGeneratedVector(StandardSequence.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.DefaultSequence.getGeneratedVector(DefaultSequence.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.Sequence.getGeneratedVector(Sequence.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager$Preallocation_Transaction_NoAccessor_State.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.assignSequenceNumber(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4388)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:596)
    at za.co.ezimax.rest.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sequence" does not exist
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2468)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:309)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: GenerationType.AUTO should not be used at all

Comment: Indeed. The actual type depends on the database, so it's neither portable nor clear what implementation is used.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli When I change the GenerationType to SEQUENCE, then exception changes to Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "seq_gen_sequence" does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned you want to use sequences with JPA.

So you have to use the GenerationType.SEQUENCE and configure the name of the sequence:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "sequence-generator"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "sequence-generator",
    sequenceName = "the_sequence_name"
)
private long id;
```

Replace the_sequence_name with the name of the sequence in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I also had to add `allocationSize = 1` to `@SequenceGenerator` like so `@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "sequence-generator",
    sequenceName = "the_sequence_name",
    allocationSize = 1
)`

Answer (score 1):

In your case `GenerationType.AUTO` translates to `GenerationType.TABLE`. The code is expecting that there's a table named `SEQUENCE` containing the values of the sequences. Since it doesn't exist, EclipseLink can't provide you with generated ids.

Either create the table (and the sequence row in it) or use a different `GenerationType`.

Comment: When I change the GenerationType to SEQUENCE, then exception changes to Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "seq_gen_sequence" does not exist @Kayaman

Comment: @Hendré if you want autogeneration, look into EclipseLink documentation. Or you can create the sequence yourself.

Comment: The sequence exists. It was automatically created when I created the table with pgAdmin.

Comment: @Hendré is the sequence in the same schema as the table? What's the stacktrace with the sequence approach?

Comment: @Hendré Maybe there is also a trigger or default value that uses the sequence. Kind of auto increment. Check this out and if you find such a trigger or default value the GenerationType would be IDENTITY

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No default value and no trigger.